# How do I click an <a> tag with role=button using xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a HTML code here that uses the `<a role='button'>` tag as a button.

```
<li class="page">
  <a role="button" class="page-link" tabindex="0" aria-label="Page 2">2</a>
</li>
```

How do I use selenium and xpath to make the  tag clickable? This is what I have so far and it seems it did not perform the click as I hope it would.

```
       def nextPage(self):
            PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe"
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

            link = 'https://seedly.sg/reviews/' + self.isp
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(2)

            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,3000)")
            nextButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@role='button' and text()='2']"))
            )

            nextButton.click()
            nextButton.close()
```

Comment: what does click does ? are you seein any error

Comment: The .click() does nothing. No error. It supposed to be a transition to page 2

Comment: You have website link ?

Comment: https://seedly.sg/reviews/sim-only-mobile-plans/m1

Answer (score 1):

You have to scroll the page until visible of the element then only you can click
[Helpfull link for scrool page](https://www.guru99.com/scroll-up-down-selenium-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @Justin stated that you need to scroll the page so that element you are searching is visible on the page and then click the element.

```
driver.get("https://seedly.sg/reviews/sim-only-mobile-plans/m1");
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,900)") #you can make an adjust 800 or 1000
nextButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@role='button' and text()='2']")))
nextButton.click()
```

To make the element unique i have changed the `xpath` as well.

Comment: Hmm, it does scrolls down to the desired area. However, it still doesn't click. My browser just closes itself. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @user3195396 : I am able to click with scroll. you have to check your window size and use the limit either 700/800/900/1000 and check

Comment: @user3195396 : One more option you have after `driver.get()` and `time.sleep(2)` before nextButton that should work as well.

Comment: It seems to work nicely with 3000 (is this normal?) without the browser closes itself. Anyway, it is still non clickable due to an ElementClickInterceptedException error "Message: element click intercepted: Element <a ... >2</a>  is not clickable at point (333, 14)"

Comment: I haven’t face that issue. However to get rid of intercepted issue use JavaScript executor to click on the next button.

Comment: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextButton)